# DELETE projects where more than 2 employee involved

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following schema:

> employee(fname,lname,e_no,age,address,sex,slary,dept_number)
>
> dpartment(dept_name,dept_number,dept_location)
>
> project(pname,pnumber,plocation,dept_number)
>
> works_on(e_no,pnumber,hours)

I want to delete the projects where more than 2 employee involved. For this purpose I made the following query.

But it is not getting executed. How I can fix this query?

```
 DELETE FROM project
 WHERE project.pnumber IN (SELECT project.pnumber 
                           FROM project
                             JOIN works_on ON project.pnumber = works_on.pnumber
                           GROUP BY project.pname
                           HAVING COUNT(works_on.e_no) > 2))
```

Comment: Try `GROUP BY project.pnumber` instead. (Can't you search works_on directly?)

Comment: What does it mean that the query does not get executed? Does it reurn an error message? If yes, then exactly what? My guess is that you cannot select from a table from which you are deleting the rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
DELETE p FROM project p
    WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM works_on w WHERE w.pnumber = p.pnumber) > 2;
```

There are several reasons why I prefer this method.

First, it can take advantage of an index on `works_on(pnumber)`.  Second, it gets around a large file sort.  I think MySQL can even run the aggregation using the index.

In addition, if there are other conditions -- such as projects that were created in the past year -- then the correlated subquery could be much more efficient, because the aggregation only needs to run on the matching projects.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM project
WHERE project.pnumber IN (SELECT w.pnumber 
                          FROM works_on w
                          GROUP BY w.pnumber
                          HAVING COUNT(w.e_no) > 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM project
 WHERE project.pnumber IN (
   SELECT pnumber
   FROM (
     SELECT project.pnumber 
     FROM project JOIN works_on 
     ON project.pnumber=works_on.pnumber
     GROUP BY project.pname
     HAVING COUNT(works_on.e_no) > 2) as t
)
```

Using this trick you circumvent the error:

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'project' for update
>   in FROM clause

that you get when you execute your statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete from a table you are selecting from at the same time. Make a temp table like this

```
DELETE FROM project
WHERE project.pnumber IN 
(
   select * from
   (
      SELECT project.pnumber 
      FROM project
      JOIN works_on ON project.pnumber = works_on.pnumber
      GROUP BY project.pname
      HAVING COUNT(works_on.e_no) > 2)
   ) tmp
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. Its working fine in SQL Server 201.

```
DECLARE @project TABLE (pname char(10),pnumber int,plocation char(10),dept_number int)
DECLARE @works_on TABLE (e_no int,pnumber int ,hours int)

INSERT INTO @project
(pname,pnumber,plocation,dept_number)
VALUES
('DB',1,'NY',5),
('CK',2,'NY',5),
('SB',3,'NY',5)

INSERT INTO @works_on
(e_no,pnumber,hours)
VALUES
(1,1,3),
(2,1,5),
(3,2,5),
(4,3,5),
(5,1,5)

DELETE FROM @project WHERE pnumber IN
    (
    SELECT wo.pnumber FROM @works_on wo
    GROUP BY wo.pnumber
    HAVING count(wo.pnumber)>1
)
```